# How to cleanup EFI boot list

Tags: boot, uefi, efi

I'm reinstalling my OSes multiple times trying to setup a dual boot and my motherboard boot list starts to get ugly : 2 entries `Windows boot` only one works, 2 entries for linux and none work. How to delete those boot options, where are they ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any BCD editing software to remove them, for example, [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) or [Visual BCD](https://www.boyans.net/)

Comment: The *EFI* boot list is stored in NVRAM and is not managed by the tools you mention (AFAIK), although [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) will manage them. That said, it could be that it's the Windows BCD that's showing those options; it's just unclear from the problem description what the case actually is.